# JavaScript isn't working on my server

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cdn

This code is working on other test environment but not on mine.

Do you know why?

I am using Amazon EC2 and Cotendo CDN.

The result I am getting is a blank page.

Thanks in advance!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Geo Test</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.101greatgoals.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $.getJSON( "http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?",
        function(data){            
            console.log(data);
            var c = data.countryCode;
            if(c=="US" || c=="US" ){
                document.getElementById('ddd').innerHTML = 'US'; } else {
                    document.getElementById('ddd').innerHTML = 'Not US';}
            /*
            this service needs ip
            var ip = data.host;
            alert(ip);
            $.getJSON( "http://freegeoip.net/json/"+ip,
                function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            );*/
        }
    );

});?
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ddd"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What isn't working? Why is this related to your server? What does EC2 have to do with all this? Please focus on your issue.

Comment: what is the error you are getting and what do you mean by not working??

Comment: This code is giving me a good result (US or Not US) if I test it on jsfiddle.net. I am not getting anything (blank page) and would like to know if you can help me with that. I am just giving more information because maybe it will help (EC2, Cotendo, etc..)

Comment: @YuvalAdam I have added this code:<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script> at least loading all the code now.. still nothing appears under the "ddd" div

Comment: Do you see errors in the JavaScript console?  Is there really a `?` at the end of your script as there is in the code you posted here?

Comment: took off the ? at the end and it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
```

to that:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
```

It's necessary, because inside http://www.101greatgoals.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1 you've already got a call of `jQuery.noConflict();` , so jQuery is not accessible by using the `$`

...and also remove the ? (see Pointy's comment above)